# Running docker container inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, streamlit

I have built a docker image of my app (streamlit) and inside my image, I have another image which I want to run as it is a search engine inside my app.

I was doing this before (outside of dockerizing the app) via subprocess

```
filepath = '"C:/Users/k.queenan/Documents/wsearch/docker/search-engine:/home" '
p = subprocess.Popen ('docker run -v' + filepath + 'search-image' , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

which worked fine. I am getting an error now saying that the filepath is not valid. How can I get around this inside the dockerized version?

Comment: Why not run them on the same host and communicate through the network (use docker-compose for multi container setups)

Comment: do you have more info or a link? Ta.

Comment: Yes, but you can find many of them if you search for docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/)

Comment: is it not possible to do it with docker inside docker?

Comment: It is possible, but should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method called [DinD](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) (Docker in Docker), but it should be used for developing the docker itself.

By security perspective it is not secure, because your parent container needs privileged rights. (You also can control the docker daemon itself from a container by mounting the docker unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock` - but you need privileged rights too - so it depends on your use case, but its not recommended)

Use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/) instead.

A sample multi-container yaml file (this method completely matches your use case):

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    image: node:12-alpine
    command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DB: todos

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todos

volumes:
  todo-mysql-data:
```

**Update**

If you want to control the docker host from a container with python, you can do the following:

Map the docker socket for your container with (on windows):

```
docker run -v "//var/run/docker.sock://var/run/docker.sock" your_python_image
```

and use `docker.py` to control your docker host from inside a container (instead of subprocess):

```
>>> import docker
>>> c = docker.from_env()
>>> stdout = c.containers.run(image="search-image:latest",command="your_command", remove=True)
```

Comment: okay so once I have my compose file, how would I replace my subprocess line inside my app? I am currently activating subprocess to run when I click  search button. This runs the search engine docker image.

Comment: so you are using the docker container as a cli tool?

Comment: yes, currently that is what I am doing :D

Comment: i c, i've updated my answer

Comment: Do I need changes in the dockerfile? I am getting error "Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))"

Comment: Your are on windows using linux containers?